Abundance of divergence-free vector fields in noncompact manifolds
Let $(M,g)$ be a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold of dimension $n \geq 2$. How big is the space $D_b(M)$ of (pointwise) bounded divergence-free vector fields on $M$ of noncompact support? I already know that the space of compactly supported divergence-free vector fields is infinite dimensional, as in this post.
